# Is it necessary to install X Code for c++ compiler? What if I install X Code and Uninstall it? Will g++ compiler will also get deleted?

Tags: c++, xcode, g++, macbookpro-touch-bar

I am not sure if I should delete the X Code as it takes a lot of space on MacBook. I want to use g++ compiler for compiling my c++ program.

Comment: You should probably leave Xcode installed.  If you want GCC in particular, I recommend `brew install gcc` (q.v. [brew](https://brew.sh/)), but still keep Xcode installed.

Comment: homebrew requires, at a minimum, the Xcode command line tools to be installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to install just the Xcode command line tools. Open Terminal and execute `xcode-select --install`. This will get you your compiler (clang, not g++. g++ is just an alias for clang++ on Macs), linker, make, etc.

To actually answer your question, yes. If you install something and then uninstall it, the stuff that got installed will get uninstalled.

If you want the actual g++ compiler, you will need to install it yourself, homebrew is the easiest way. The gcc package will create versioned symlinks for you (`g++-9`), and you can just use that, or create another symlink that redirects `g++` to `g++-9`. If you did that, you'll have to remember to manually update that symlink when the major version changes. All this is found in `usr/local/bin` after installing homebrew and the `gcc` package.